# The Adventures of Indiana Jones compatible with Top Secret/S.I.?

Tags: tsr

TSR's [*The Adventures of Indiana Jones*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones_%28role-playing_game%29) came out in 1984. Three years later TSR produced the total revamp of *Top Secret* with [*Top Secret/S.I.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Secret/S.I.) It appears that a lot of the fundamental system from the Indiana Jones game formed the base of the new Top Secret/S.I. game. Where can I find an article or reference to how compatible the two systems may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's very little out there about this ancient game. However, [this discussion](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?395624-Indiana-Jones-TSR-WEG/page2) may suggest some similarities:

> My memory about the specifics of the system are pretty vague, but I remember once having memorized the action/results/whatever chart on the back of the rulebook. It was color coded and pretty simple, as I recall, and damage wasn't hit points but some sort of descriptive thing where you could take so many "bruises" before being knocked out and so many "wounds" before dying. This and Marvel Super Heroes would lead me to be confused by systems where you couldn't knock anybody out; just outright kill 'em (and that's most systems in existence at the time, by my reckoning). I never associated it with Top Secret S.I., but now that I think about it, it definitely had a similar if not identical percentile based resolution system for combat and skills.